# Django. Inline formset with existing instances of model in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I use Django 1.7.11 and python 2.7. I have two models:

```
class Adv(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class ImageFile(models.Model):
   file = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_imgname, max_length=50, blank=True)
   adv = models.ForeignKey(Adv)
```

Instance of Adv can have 10 image files. ImageFile is inline in admin. I need in the template show the instance of Adv with all it's image files and image files must be with form to delete or chance it. 
What is the best way to do it? I tryed **inlineformset_factory** but it show only form with file input without existing image files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using formset?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets 
Try this. I havent tried it out but I did something similar in my project and it worked. I hope it helps.

forms.py

```
class AdvForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Adv
  fields = ['title','description']

class ImageFileForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = ImageFile
  fields = ['file','adv']
```

in your views.py,

do something like pass your instance of adv

```
def getAdv(request, adv_instance_id):
 adv = get_object_or_404(Adv, pk = adv_instance_id)
 ImgFileformSet = modelformset_factory(ImageFile, form = ImageFileForm)

 if request.method == 'POST':
  Adv = AdvForm(request.POST, instance=adv)
  ImgFiles = ImgFileformSet (request.POST, queryset = ImageFile.objects.filter(adv=adv_instance_id), prefix='images', )
 // your code

return render(request, 'yourtemplate', {'adv_instance_id','Adv','ImgFiles'})
```

and display the data in your template.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!